# Map function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to create a tagging function that can have multiple tags per data.

I use map for my select which is like this:

```
value = {
  form.tags.map(item => ({
    value: item,
    label: item
  }))
}
```

My existing data do not have tags value in them, how do make sure that if there is no data I can push in an empty array into the input?

Comment: optional chaining, conditional operator

Comment: Did you try for something like @keikai said? `form.tags.length > 0 ? form.tags.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item })) : []`?